# dynamic update ios apple-touch-icon from web app

Tags: php, html, ios, web-applications, mobile

I'm trying to see if updating a mobile app icon image is possible, without opening the page again.

My DEMO is here: http://charliehield.com/sandbox/IconUpdate

Step 1: navigate to the URL on iOS device (haven't tested Android, but should work)
Step 2: Click the arrow button and select "Add to Home Screen"
Step 3: Click "Add" button

Now, the icon should be green.

I'm using a simple PHP if statement for testing, setting $i = 0;

So, if $i = 0, set the apple-touch-icon to GREEN.png, else use RED.png

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>IconUpdate</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <!-- Adding "maximum-scale=1" fixes the Mobile Safari auto-zoom bug: http://filamentgroup.com/examples/iosScaleBug/ -->
    <?php

    if ($i == 0) {

        echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="green.png">';

    } else {

        echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="red.png">';

    }

    ?>

</head>

<body lang="en">

add to home screen for DEMO

</body>

</html>
```

The way it works, is I can manually change $i and if it's not = 0, and I click the icon, open the page in Mobile Safari, then press the home button, the icon will be RED.png

I'm wondering if there's a way to "push" (for lack of a better word) the new icon to the homescreen without having to re-open the page? Can this be done?

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ive done some experimenting and found if you can format up a fullscreen image on the page, and leave out the icon meta tag, the icon will become a thumbnail image of the page each time you reload.

vivvvi.

Comment: Yea, I've done that too. Ideally what I'd like is it to change w/o having to open the app. It's not possible at this time tough.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that with iOS 7.1 a new icon will automatically be downloaded when your installed web-app is run.

This is what I am using to reference the icons:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="icon.png"/>

<!-- iOS 7 iPad (retina) -->
<link href="/images/icon_152x152.png" sizes="152x152" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 6 iPad (retina) -->
<link href="/images/icon_144x144.png" sizes="144x144" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 7 iPhone (retina) -->
<link href="/images/icon_120x120.png" sizes="120x120" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 6 iPhone (retina) -->
<link href="/images/icon_114x114.png" sizes="114x114" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 7 iPad -->
<link href="/images/icon_76x76.png" sizes="76x76" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 6 iPad -->
<link href="/images/icon_72x72.png" sizes="72x72" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iOS 6 iPhone -->
<link href="/images/icon_57x57.png" sizes="57x57" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="/images/icon_196x196.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, there is no way (on a stock OS device using public APIs) for either a native app or a web clipping to change its icon (other than badging a native app).